# Load entire html file to parse with php?

Tags: php, html, search

i try to parse a website's html file with php fopen(). Thats works so far very well but the problem is, that there are serveral posts on the site that aren't shown in the html file, because u have to scroll far down until the posts load.

As an example, i try to count the total amount of comments in my own facebook page. (Just an example, if it's shown somewhere on facebook, that doesn't help me)

How can I make the html file load completely?

Thank you

Comment: As the content is loaded by Javascript as the page loads, you will have to use something like php-webdriver.  This is quite a big step, so make sure this is actually what you want as opposed to a nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot, directly. What you are doing is called **scraping**. You have to inspect the queries made by the browser in your developer tools when viewing that page yourself, and reproduce those queries in php through fopen() or any other means (CUrl, etc...)

Comment: Can u maybe give me some more informations about this? What tools can i use to do this?

Comment: @felix9607 There are no "tools" that can or would do this for you. What you are trying to accomplish is the task of reverse engineering and copying an existing service. You have to make sure to get eventual access with your user accoutn to the other service, maybe aquire an auth token and with this make requests to the API, fetch the information and render it on your website. Websites are for a reason server-sided and not fully readable to the client. You cannot simply copy dynamic websites behaviour like this except you invest alot of development and knowledge into it. Very special thing.